# Ленивые квантификаторы

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Имеется такое регулярное выражение:

```regex
(?(?<=\[){"index":".+?","text":"((?!e).)*?"},?|,?{"index":".+?","text":"((?!e).)*?"})
```

Главная часть:

```regex
{"index":".+?","text":"((?!e).)*?"}
```

Где я пытаюсь найти такой элемент, в тексте которого нет символа e.

Пытаюсь найти совпадение в такой строке:

```
[{"index":"1","text":"Hello"},{"index":"2","text":"Bye"},{"index":"3","text":"15"}]
```

Должно подходить только "{"index":"3","text":"15"}", так как там нет символа "e" в тексте, но .+? выделает весь текст, хоть он и ленивый. Почему так?
У меня есть предположение, что так происходит из-за того, что +? пытается найти такое совпадение, при котором остаток паттерна тоже будет подходить, то есть идёт до самого конца. Как этого избежать?

Comment: `.+?` означает вообще любые символы, поэтому под первое же такое определение попадает полностью вся строка от первого text и до конца, что отлично видно в отладке https://regex101.com/r/Lvky7R/1/

Comment: И кстати не понятно зачем вообще понадобилась вот та альтернатива с `.+?`. Ну и НЕ `e` стоило бы записать в виде `[^e]*` вместо `((?!e).)*`

Comment: Я это понимаю, но это же ленивый квантификатор, он должен найти все символы, до следующего символа паттерна, то есть до ".

Comment: Это просто пример, вообще там вместо индекса url, по этому там .+?, а "e" - это пример поиска, там может быть любая строка.

Comment: Нет, лень заключается только в "захватить как можно меньше, при условии совпадения всего дальнейшего выражения хотя бы один раз"

Comment: А можно ли сделать так, что-бы оно выделяло до следующего символа в паттерне?

Comment: так что вместо `.` можно написать например `[^"]`. Только разбирать json регулярками неблагодарное занятие. Вы например не учитываете что `"text:"Hello \"World\""` вполне себе нормальный json ...

Comment: Заменить это на что-то типо такого [^"]+? ?

Comment: ну да, что бы быть уверенным, что мы точно идем до следующей кавычки а не как то иначе